# group by Query not working fine sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

```
Exp                      Reason    CreditAccounts   Points  
2012-01-30 02:11:58.830  Inactive   1               5           
2012-01-31 02:11:58.827  Inactive   1               5   
2012-02-01 02:12:02.130  Inactive   2               10  
2012-02-03 02:11:58.820  Inactive   4               20  
2012-02-03 02:12:02.120  Inactive   2               10  
2012-02-04 02:12:02.113  Inactive   4               20
```

i should  get the result like this, i tried group by but nothing works like the way i need  here

```
Exp                      Reason    CreditAccounts   Points  
2012-01-30 02:11:58.830  Inactive   1               5           
2012-01-31 02:11:58.827  Inactive   1               5   
2012-02-01 02:12:02.130  Inactive   2               10  
2012-02-03 02:11:58.820  Inactive   6               30  
2012-02-04 02:12:02.113  Inactive   4               20
```

any solution on this would be great
Thanks
prince

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to group by date? You have neglected to include any additional information about your table definitions or requirements but probably need something like

```
SELECT MIN(Exp) AS Exp,
       Reason,
       SUM(CreditAccounts) AS CreditAccounts,
       SUM(Points) AS Points
FROM SomeTable
GROUP BY  Reason,  DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, Exp)
```

Comment: Thanks Works  great Martin Smith